# SQL Server : turning rows into columns (pivot, but with a twist)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to compress multiple rows of a table into 1 row but multiple columns.

I looked at a few methods but none of them seem to be right for what I need.
The (main) problem being there is no 'heading' data in the table which ruins the pivot method.

Basically I have 2 tables I am trying to join, and I am trying to get only the first 3 items (anything more than 3 I don't care about).

So my 2 tables are created and filled.

```
CREATE TABLE [order] ( ID INT )
CREATE TABLE OrderItem ( OrderID INT, Item VARCHAR(20) )

insert into [order] values (1)
insert into [order] values (2)

insert into orderitem values (1, 'Hammer')
insert into orderitem values (2, 'Spoon')
insert into orderitem values (2, 'Potato')
insert into orderitem values (2, 'shed')
```

And I want my results like this:

```
ID  Item1   Item2   Item3  
1   Hammer  NULL    NULL  
2   Potato  shed    Spoon
```

I've looked at a few methods of using `PIVOT`, but because I don't have any 'headings' for each value, and because there are many thousands of possible unique `[Item]` values in `[OrderItem]` I can't figure out how to get a query to do what I want.

The only way I have managed to do it with some ugly ranking joins - which works great but it is **hideously slow**.

(the query without the joins takes a fraction of a second to complete, but takes upwards of 2-3 minutes once they are included because of the amount of data its looking at)

```
SELECT 
    o.ID, i1.Item, i2.Item, i3.Item 
FROM
    [order] o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
         *, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId ORDER BY item) AS iRank
     FROM 
         OrderItem) AS i1 ON i1.OrderID = o.ID AND i1.iRank = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
         *, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId ORDER BY item) AS iRank
     FROM 
         OrderItem) AS i2 ON i2.OrderID = o.ID AND i2.iRank = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
         *, 
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId ORDER BY item) AS iRank
     FROM 
         OrderItem) AS i3 ON i3.OrderID = o.ID AND i2.iRank = 3
```

Can anyone recommend a better method to look at that won't completely kill my database when it is being run?

Answer (score 2):

Although you can do this with `pivot`, it might be easier to just use conditional aggregation:

```
select oi.OrderId,
       max(case when iRank = 1 then oi.Item end) as item1,
       max(case when iRank = 2 then oi.Item end) as item2,
       max(case when iRank = 3 then oi.Item end) as item3
from (select oi.*,
             rank() over (partition by orderId order by item) as iRank
      from OrderItem oi
     ) oi 
group by oi.OrderId;
```

Answer (score 2):

Update- Since the number of order items are indeterminate, I converted this into a dynamic PIVOT

```
DECLARE @qu NVARCHAR(MAX), @pcol NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT   @pcol= COALESCE(@pcol + ',','') + ItemNumber FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT N'Item'+ CAST (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID Order by Item) AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS ItemNumber 
  FROM OrderItem) A

SET @qu=N'SELECT OrderId,'+ @pcol + N' FROM 
(
  SELECT 
  OrderID,N''Item''+ CAST (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID Order by Item) AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS ItemNumber, Item FROM OrderItem
  )S
  PIVOT
  (
  MAX(Item) 
    FOR ItemNumber IN ('+@pcol +N')) AS piv'
EXEC sp_executesql @qu
```

Update SQL fiddle link:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0cd9d0/17

**EDIT -** Original Answer:

> Using Pivot for known maximum number of order items, this can be done
>   like
>
> ```
> SELECT OrderId,[Item1],[Item2],[Item3],[Item4],[Item5],[Item6]
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT 
>   OrderID,N'Item'+ CAST (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID Order by Item) AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS ItemNumber, Item FROM OrderItem
>   )S
>   PIVOT
>   (
>   MAX(Item) 
>     FOR ItemNumber IN ([Item1],[Item2],[Item3],[Item4],[Item5],[Item6])
>   )piv
> ```
>
> Sql fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0cd9d0/4