# join tables without common field in sqlserver one in veritcal and other in horizontal

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables one is accounts where users user stored his multiple accounts and other is reports table where we have stored the number of reports but there is no link between them.

```
table 1 (accounts)

accountid | contactId | accountname
121           12        personal
122           12        official

table 2 (Reports)

Reportid | ReportName
 1          bankstatment
 2          panreport
 3          other report
```

Now I want this output

```
account | contactid| reportid | reportname   | ReportId | ReportName   | ReportId | ReportName

121       12           1       bankstatment    2          panreport       3          other report
122       12           1       bankstatment    2          panreport       3          other report
```

How I can make it in SQL Server query ? I am asking this because I am not able to identify which account has selected which report in mvc.net in grid form

Comment: You need `pivot` + `cross join`. `Cross join` will make connection between every account and every report - all from 1 x all from 2 table. `Pivot` will make columns for each report.

Comment: can you make this query ?

Comment: @ DhruvJoshi  : Please check my quesion below your answers please I have one concern is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**
I am basically `CROSS JOIN`ing the `accounts` table  with the `PIVOT` on the `reports` table.
This allows us to generate the desired output of all reports in a single row for each account.

Please try this query:

```
select 
    a.*, 
    1 as reportid,
    [1] as reportname,
    2 as reportid,
    [2] as reportname,
    3 as reportid,
    [3] as reportname 
from 
    accounts a
cross join 
(
    select [1],[2],[3]
    from
    (select * from Reports) s
    pivot
    (Max(ReportName) for Reportid in ([1],[2],[3]))p
)t
```

sql fiddle for demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/703c4/9

Comment: Hi DhruvJoshi,thanks for your query its works I have just one question can you please explain your query what does means [1],[2] and why we used pivot and all.. it would be appreciated if you explain it so that in future might be it will help me

Comment: one more concerns is here I have 7 reports and it could be 3 or 10 then how i will manage ? I means to say i have 7 records (reports) and in your query it will bring first 3 only what about the others ? I want to make it dynamic if report table has 3 reports then your query is fine but what if it is 5 then ?

Comment: @Ramanverma Please study the `pivot` syntax to gain familiarity with it. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx  We are using the report id data in the inner query part after `pivot` keyword to transpose values. See this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/703c4/11 for demo. Once transposed we can easily apply `CROSS JOIN` to join both tables.

Comment: although we can create a dynamic pivot, but I'd recommend manually typing the report id like `[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]` where ever we have `[1],[2],[3]` if the number of reports is constant. For an example of dynamic pivot  see my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658139/sql-server-turning-rows-into-columns-pivot-but-with-a-twist/31659110#31659110

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:  **Not Possible**

If there are 5 Bank Statements report in your `report table`, and 5 entries in your `Accounts table`, how would you know which report belongs to which account?

Also the last comment "*I am not able to identify which account has selected which report in mvc.net in grid form*" of your question is a different thing to what you have shown in your example. If you have fixed number of reports and you want a column for each of those report type, then yes, but if you want selected reports for each account, then you need to store that selection somewhere.

Comment: It is possible. Look at the example - he needs to show all report for each account. This is possible - see my comment.

Comment: read the question: *I am not able to identify which account has selected which report in mvc.net in grid form*

Comment: I know his final dataset can be achieved, but question says something else

Comment: Yes, but exmaple imlies other - all accounts with all reports. If you are right - yes, not possible.

Comment: I think it should be possible once we will display in the grid then it will be easy to identify and can store in the database. but I dont know how I can achieve it